# how to create firstDayOfMonth and lastDayOfMonth functions using momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Working in javascript I stoped in a very simple question about how to get the first day of month and the lastday of the month using javascript and momentjs.
I know that in vb should be somethign like:

```
 Public Function LastDayOfMonth(ByVal current As DateTime) As DateTime
    Dim daysInMonth As Integer = DateTime.DaysInMonth(current.Year, current.Month)
    Return current.FirstDayOfMonth().AddDays(daysInMonth - 1)
End Function

 Public Function FirstDayOfMonth(ByVal current As DateTime) As DateTime
    Return current.AddDays(1 - current.Day)
End Function
```

How I shall move this code to javascript + momentjs? I think the library doesn't similar methods.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the format of the functions attribute `DateTime`? What are you expecting the functions to return, the day number (1-31) or a string (Monday-Sunday)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know VB and your question is not clear as to your input-output requirements. Here is a solution as far as I understand it. It is not using moments.js but is POJS. You can easily convert it to using moments if you should wish (don't know why you would).

Javascript

```
function firstDayOfMonth() {
    var d = new Date(Date.apply(null, arguments));

    d.setDate(1);
    return d.toISOString();
}

function lastDayOfMonth() {
    var d = new Date(Date.apply(null, arguments));

    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
    d.setDate(0);
    return d.toISOString();
}

var now = Date.now();

console.log(firstDayOfMonth(now));
console.log(lastDayOfMonth(now));
```

Output

```
2013-06-01T21:22:48.000Z 
2013-06-30T21:22:48.000Z
```

See [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for formats

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/s3E74/)

Using moments, you could do this.

Javascript

```
console.log(moment().startOf('month').utc().toString());
console.log(moment().endOf("month").utc().toString());
```

Output

```
2013-06-01T00:00:00+02:00
2013-06-30T23:59:59+02:00
```

See [moments](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for format

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/FFsFd/)